# Sync huge file tree with rsyncd, and encryption

Tags: sync, rsync, wan

I need to do daily copy of large file tree over the public internet, and do that effectively. As far as I know, if I use **rsyncd** on receive part then sync is done quite effectively since during file tree compare part both sides (sender and receiver) can scan existing file trees locally. This way, I suppose to sync to rsyncd and that's fine, but the sending will be in plain text and I need to encrypt it since I use public Internet.

On the contrary, if I run sync like this: `rsync -a /localtree user@host:/remotetree/` then all is done by the same (local) rsync, it uses ssh to login to remote system, scan its filesystem and do the sync. Then I get encryption on all phases but the remote tree scan is not that effective.

**So, looks like rsyncd is for effectiveness and rsync (over ssh) is for secureness?** Do I have an option to use rsyncd securely without need to setup (explicit) VPN between hosts?

Please advice, since syncing files seems to be wildly used around and I suppose just miss something on encryption part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption that rsync over ssh (remote shell) will mean your local rsync gets to do all the work, is not correct.

When using a command like `rsync -a /localtree user@host:/remotetree/` to rsync to a remote system over ssh, there are two `rsync` instances at work: the local one (started by you) and a remote one (started by the remote shell). Both instances communicate via pipes through the remote shell.

The process is described [here](https://rsync.samba.org/how-rsync-works.html).

Which means that, when connecting to a remote system with `rsync` through ssh, scanning remote files is handled by the remote rsync "server" (not to be confused with the rsyncd daemon) instance so it is just as effective as scanning locally.